# Which method is better way to store information in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to store user `Likes` into database. But I am not sure which one of these 2 methods is better:

in my situation, users can like `Posts`, `Comments` and `Groups`. something like Facebook.

Assume there are 10 million likes for : `Posts`, `Comments` and `Groups`

**Method A:**

Create a **`Like`** table, and add a `LikeType` field in it:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| likeID | LikeType | userID |
+--------+----------+--------+
|   1    |    1     |    1   | // User 1 liked a post
+--------+----------+--------+
|   2    |    2     |    1   | // User 1 liked a comment
+--------+----------+--------+
|   3    |    3     |    1   | // User 1 liked a group
```

which `LikeType` includes : 1,2,3
1 = Posts, 2= Comments, 3= Groups

**Method B:**

Create three separated tables for each one of Posts, Comments and Groups.

---

in Method A,

Because there are too many likes and it needs an extra condition ( `Where status = 1, or 2, or 3` ) to get a Post, Comment or Group likes, which method is better?

---

## UPDATED POST:

```
users
    uid     // PK
---------------------------------------
itemTypes
    typeID          // PK
    typeText        // comments, groups, posts
---------------------------------------

--------------------------------------- +
posts                                   |
        id              // PK           |
        typeID          // 1            |
        ...                             |
--------------------------------------- +
comments                                |
        id              // PK           |
        typeID          // 2            |
        ...                             |
--------------------------------------- + Items
groups                                  |
        id              // PK           |
        typeID          // 3            |
        ...                             |
--------------------------------------- +
photos                                  |
        id              // PK           |
        typeID          // 4            |
        ...                             |
--------------------------------------- +

---------------------------------------
likes
    uid                // FK to user id
    itemid             // FK to posts, groups, photos, comments id
    itemType           // FK to itemsTypes.typeID



// select post #50 likes
SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE itemid = 50 and itemType = 1

// select comment #50 of user #2
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE itemid = 50 and uid = 2 and itemType = 2
```

is this a good schema ?

Comment: What are you going to do with that information? This may very much determine your storage. Do you also want to store **who** liked what? I assume your LikeID is the item they liked. Please update your question.

Comment: yes, exactly, I didn't list all my `Likes` table fields, just likeType to determine what kind of like it is.

Comment: I want to have faster reading. in method A I should have a query like this: `Select * FROM Likes WHERE userid = 1 AND likeType = 1` , But in method B, query is `SELECT * FROM postsLike WHERE userid = 1`. That extra `AND likeType = 1` in method A won't take too much process in large amount of data ?

Comment: The first column in your table should be something like "likeID", right? (so it would store the ID of the thing the user liked?)

Comment: yes I updated that. the matter is the likeType field. mysql should check current row is what kind of like. in large number of rows. does that slow down reading?

Comment: I updated post, please take a look. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like either of your methods.   I would go more normalized.   I would have a table for item types, such as comments, groups, posts, etc.   Then I would have a table for items.  It would have an ItemId as the PK and a FK reference to item types.  There would also be a users table.   Finally, the likes table would be a many to many relationship between items and users.

Comment: well, this is a good way, but for getting just one like, it should look in three tables. imagine if there are 10 million likes. and 100 likes should be fetched. is this method fast beside normalized ?

Comment: I think you're suffering a bit from premature optimization, ali A.  While it's true that core database design decisions can have profound impacts on performance, the fact is that modern RDBMS are very very good at doing precisely what you're worrying about -- finding indexed information.  Picking out 100 matching rows from a set of 10 million records is a piece of cake for any competent database system.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan Doggen said, what you're doing with the information is an important consideration.  In particular, if you want to be able to ask the question "what things does a given user like", then you will benefit from having all the data in one table -- otherwise, you'd have to have three separate queries to answer that question.

For the case of the question "which people like a given thing", the performance difference between the single-table model and the multiple-table model should be relatively small if your tables are properly indexed (with an index on likeID/likeType, in this case).  The multiple-table model will make your application logic more complex, and will be harder to extend in the future when you want to add other things a user might be able to like.

Comment: It looks pretty good, and reflects pretty much what Dan Bracuk was suggesting, except he was suggesting putting all your items in one table, rather than separate photos/comments/groups/posts tables.  I think you're probably better off with separate tables as you have shown, because photos/comments/groups/posts are probably fundamentally different types of items, with different characteristics, and probably would not happily co-exist in the same table.

Comment: My only additional suggestion would be that you don't need typeID in the posts/comments/groups/posts tables, because it will be the same for every single row in each of those tables.  This adds no value and just consumes storage.

Comment: you're right, i was thinking about that, typeID is not needed. thank you. :)

Comment: in fact, I am going to make a social network for my country people only, and I know it will grow very fast, when we talking about social network, we talk about huge number of rows and data. I am worry about whenever the number of rows in `likes` table reaches to 1 billion and more. I'm thinking about that time...